Name of film in which some boy built spaceship
I saw some film on Disney Channel years ago. It was about one boy and his relative, who built spaceship to deliver some package to another ship which was in the space.
When they tested the ship, it started to burn and then some scientists helped them. I think they had laptops, so it can't be that old.
Do you know what film it is?

How many is "many years ago"? You'd be surprised on how long laptops have been around.

I think it was at least 2006.

I'm thinking of a 90's movie that sounds very similar except for the space ship part; especially because you mentioned it's all realistic. Are you sure the rocket/space ship was meant to be sent to an actual ship in space?

I'm not sure. I found The Astronaut Farmer, but that isn't it.

I found it. It's called Project Mercury or Rocket's Red Glare. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0219279/

There was a movie from 1985 called The Explorers with Ethan Hawke and River Phoenix. He makes a starship out of a carnival ride. It wasn't Disney though, it was Paramount. Not sure if they used a laptop.

That isn't that film. In the film was everything real, no magic energy etc. I don't know for sure that it was Disney.
